# How to manage growing C++ project

Tags: c++, netbeans, scons

I am wondering how I should manage a growing C++ project. Now, I am developing a project with Netbeans and it's dirty work generating makefiles. The project has become too big and I have decided to split it up into a few parts. What is the best way of doing this?

I am trying to use Scons as my build system. I have had some success with it, but should I edit the build scripts every time I append or delete files. It's too dull.

So I need your advice.

P.S. By the way, how does a large project like google chrome do this? Does everybody use some kind of IDE to build scripts generated only for software distribution?

Comment: In many companies there is a dedicated position called something like "Buildmeister". It is these peoples jobs to maintain the build environment and maybe even unit tests.

Comment: @Misha, this responsibility is often times called a Configuration Manager.

Comment: @Misha and what about workflow? Is it a right way to allow for every developer write code in prefered IDE, and Buildmeister will convert their projects to one build?

Comment: @AlexPovar, you should indeed give every developer the freedom to use their preferred IDE. I cant imagine what I would do if someone forced me to use an IDE that I dont like, emacs for example :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also use Netbeans for C++ and compile with SCons. I use the jVi Netbeans plugin which really works well.

For some reason the Netbeans Python plugin is no longer official, which I dont understand at all. You can still get it though, and it really makes editing the SCons build scripts a nice experience. Even though Netbeans doesnt have a SCons plugin (yet?) you can still configure its build command to execute SCons.

As for maintaining the SCons scripts automatically by the IDE, I dont do that either, I do that by hand. But its not like I have to deal with this on a daily basis, so I dont see that its that important, especially considering how easy to read the scripts are.

Here's the build script in SCons that does the same as mentioned previously for CMake:

```
env = Environment()
env.EnsurePythonVersion(2, 5)
env.EnsureSConsVersion(2, 1)

libTarget = env.SharedLibrary(target = 'foo', source = ['a.cpp', 'b.cpp', 'c.pp'])
env.Program(target = 'bar', source = ['bar.cpp', libTarget])
```

The SCons Glob() function is a nice option, but I tend to shy away from *automatically* building all the files in a directory. The same goes for listing sub-directories to be built. Ive been burned enough times by this, and prefer explicitly specifying the file/dirs to be built.

In case you hear those rumors that SCons is slower than other alternatives, the [SCons GoFastButton](http://www.scons.org/wiki/GoFastButton) has some pointers that can help out.

Comment: Its sad but Netbeans really have no SCons support yet. But sr42 gave a good idea to use Glob(). I think that is what I really whant. BTW,why you prefer explicit specifying?

Comment: @AlexPovar, Its less common with source files, but with subdirectories I often have multiple versions of a directory (subdirA and subdirA.old for example) and if both get compiled, then you could get conflicts or unexpected runtime behavior that isnt easy to debug, since Im assuming it compiles only certain directories. Something similar can happen with source files. Also, when adding new source files, its a reminder that they need to be added to the build system ***and*** source control.

Comment: do you use intermediate makefile for calling scons from Netbeans?

Comment: That just sounds wrong :) But I have heard of people doing it. You can configure the build command in the project configuration.

Comment: and looks awful :) Seems like I choose appropriate workflow. I use Netbeans project for building library code as a program and scons for building shared library. It looks comfortable for a now, cause make it much more easier to debug library code as program.

Comment: @AlexPovar, ya I agree, I think Netbeans is a nice IDE for C++ programming. As for SCons, there are those that will say its slower than other alternative like CMake. That used to be the case in the beginning, but SCons has improved alot since then. I analyzed both SCons and CMake when we converted from Make, and in addition to the horrible CMake syntax, SCons is a much more complete solution. Try doing variant builds in CMake without having to recompile everything. I never got that to work intuitively, but it works great in SCons. Good luck with your project!

Comment: I've heard SCons slower than both CMake and Waf, but in case of my project I don't see any difference. I think SCons have great advantage over CMake because if something go wrong you can always write some hacking python code. Thank you :)

Comment: @AlexPovar, I added a link to my answer to help speed up the SCons compilation.

Comment: How to load a an existing scons based project in netbeans ?

Answer (score 4):

Most large projects stick with a build system that automatically handles all the messy details for them.  I'm a huge fan of CMake (which is what KDE uses for all their components) but scons is another popular choice.  My editor (KDevelop) supposedly handles CMake projects itself, but I still edit the build scripts myself because it's not that hard.

I'd recommend learning one tool really well and sticking with it (plenty of documentation is available for any tool you'll be interested in).  Be sure you also look into version control if you haven't already (I have a soft spot for git, but Mercurial and Subversion are also very popular choices).

---

A simple CMake example:

```
project("My Awesome Project" CXX)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
add_library(foo SHARED a.cpp b.cpp c.cpp) #we'll build an so file
add_executable(bar bar.cpp)
target_link_libraries(bar foo) #link bar to foo
```

This is obviously a trivial case, but it's very easy to manage and expand as needed.

Comment: Yes, managing build scripts by hand is not hard but it is rather simple to forget add something. Right now there are two build system in project. Makefiles are native for Netbeans but its hard for me to manage it, and Scons which is easy to use but have no IDE integration. By the way does KDevelop projects built on CMake? And yeah, I use mercurial as DCVS.

Comment: KDevelop is also built using CMake and it can maintain the project files for you.  As I said, I've never let it manage mine for me, but I'll update my answer with a simple CMake example so you can see how easy it is.

Comment: CMake is ok, its main problem is its syntax (which I always found not intuitive). You cant beat something like SCons or Waf that use Python, a true programming language. It should be just as easy (if not easier) to maintain files SCons as in CMake.

Comment: Thats the reason why I choose SCons. In case of emergency I can always do some python hacks.

Comment: I've never used SCons so I can't offer any feedback, but one of the things that's really nice about CMake is that it supports build generators for many different targets (one of my friends uses CMake to build Visual Studio solutions).  Ultimately you need to pick the tool that works best for your goals and if SCons is meeting that need I'd say stick with it.

Comment: There is one problem here. You can generate Visual Studio solution but all changes done in it will be lost. In other words you cannot do automatically reverse transformation. So this is usefull only for building on target platform.

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to use Scons as build system. I have some success with it, but I should edit 
>   build scripts every time I append or delete file. It's too dull.

Depending on how your files are organized, you can use, for example, Scon's `Glob()` function to get source files as a list without having to list all files individually. For example, to build all c++ source files into an executable, you can do:

```
 Program('program', Glob('*.cpp'))
```

You can do the same in CMake using its commands.

And, if you're using SCons, since it's Python you can write arbitrary Python code to make your source file lists.

You can also organize files into multiple folders and have subsidiary SCons (or CMakeList.txt) build files that the master build script can call.

Comment: Sounds good. I have Java-style project organization with packages. It seems to be quite good to work with directories instead of sources.